# How to slide a text, to position it, along a path?

Tags: gimp, path, text-on-path

There's a way to slide a text along a path to position it in the wished place?
In the image bellow GIMP has inserted the text at the middle of the ellipse, and the text asymmetric going toward its left.
[image]

Using rotate tool the thing get worse, the text rotates, but not along the path:
[image]

Comment: Yes  - an external script like in the answer bellow would be your option - unfortunatelly GIMP is maintained by volunteers and is understaffed event o maintain/develop the raster-editing features we want the most.

The suggestion for this kind of work is to create your inital art in a vector program, like Inkscape, and import the result into GIMP to apply raster effects if any.

Comment: For me it is 200px from the path I drew. Idk why it cannot follow the path or how gimp is that bad in writing curved text compared to ps. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard text-along-path puts the text left-justified on the path. When the path is a circle (99% of the uses) this is not a problem since the text path can be rotated around the circle center. But it's a major blocker for the remaining 1%.

There is however a script that does text-along-path but gives you more formating options (in particular, you can center the text on the path, which is what is required in most cases). This script is [here](http://gimp-path-tools.sourceforge.net/tools.shtml#text-along-path).

[image: Text on half ellipse (centered, guide path on middle of caps)]